# Name of a tool used to make spcie

Tags: nouns, image-identification

[image: **Picture of a stone tool**]

This tool is used to make spice. In the Hindi language this is called  लोढ़ा-lodha but I don't know the English word for it.

Comment: It's made of the stone

Comment: This is just a guess: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortar_and_pestle.  The part you show would be the pestle.

Comment: Do put question 'hold on" I dont wanna learn english and visit this site  again

Comment: I don't know English is the adjective or noun is written with first word capitle

Comment: If the stone (pictured) is used to grind the spice, it is called a "pestle" and is used in a stone bowl called a "mortar". Cobaltduck has included a link to a Wikipedia article showing both tools.

Comment: You say it is used to *make* spice. My understanding is that most spices are obtained from plants which grow naturally, so no one actually *makes* spice, unless one attributes it to the Almighty. The job of the pestle is to *grind* the spice.

Answer (score 0):

It is called a **[pestle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pestle&searchmode=none)** and the slab or bowl that you grind it against is a mortar.

[image]

Another name is a **pounder** or spice pounder.

> [to pound](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pound)
>
> Crush or grind (something) into a powder or paste: pound the cloves
>   with salt and pepper until smooth